# Unique column value combination with NULL values

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to conditionally insert some data into a table, where each combination of column values may only appear at most once in the table. The schema looks something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE foobar (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    a_id INTEGER,
    b_id INTEGER,
    c_id INTEGER,
    ident VARCHAR(32),
    date_a timestamp,
    date_b timestamp,
    FOREIGN KEY a_id REFERENCES a (id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY b_id REFERENCES b (id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY c_id REFERENCES c (id) ON DELETE CASCADE));
```

The combination of (a_id, b_id, c_id, ident) is unique, but only for rows where date_a AND date_b are both NULL.

I want to be able to insert a new row only if the a_id, b_id, c_id, task combination is not already in the db. if it is it doesn't have to do anything.

At first I tried to create a unique constraint on these columns, but the problem is that a_id, b_id and c_id are allowed to be NULL, as long as least one of them is not null. This ruins the unique constraint. Because the a, b and c_id fields are foreign keys, I can't set them to some other stub value (like -1).

I tried playing with locking (against my better judgement) which resulted in a deadlock within a couple of minutes of testing.

Is there any standard solution to this problem?

Comment: You want this logic as a sort of constraint/trigger (throw an error if violated)?  Or would you add this to your INSERT statement (do nothing if violated)?

Comment: If a_id, b_id, and c_id can be null, why do you want them to be foreign keys?  In fact, does postgresql even allow that?

Comment: @DanBracuk, [absolutely](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1363887/does-a-foreign-key-referencing-pk-need-the-not-null-constraint).

Comment: Can you do a select first to see if a conflicting value is already there?

Comment: What do you mean by _This ruins the unique constraint_? Nulls are considered different for the unique index. Or do you want then to be considered equal (-1) as in @Mike's answer?

Comment: Because of the NULLs rows like (1, NULL, NULL) can occur more then once, without violating the unique constraint.

Comment: As far as selecting goes, ofcourse I can just SELECT and count the results, then INSERT if the SELECT returned 0. However, another process can do the exact same thing before the first one commits. In which case you end up with the same row twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using a unique constraint, you should probably be using a unique index on the exact conditions you want to check for.  You could then coalesce the null values into a dummy value, such as -1.  Something like:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX
foobar_test ON foobar
(COALESCE(a_id, -1), COALESCE(b_id, -1), COALESCE(c_id, -1), ident) -- Nulls become -1
WHERE date_a is null and date_b is null; -- Only check when date_a and date_b is null
```

This would make sure `a_id`, `b_id`, `c_id`, and `ident` were unique (including their combination of null values) for all rows where both `date_a` and `date_b` were `null`.

Answer (score 0):

In a similar situations in multiple productive databases of mine I just **add a "default row" to referenced tables**. I use `id = 0` for these and start real surrogate keys at 10 or 100. Or you could use `-1` (or whatever suits you) if `0` is reserved.

This way I can set all fk columns to `NOT NULL DEFAULT 0` and (partial) `UNIQUE` constraints work out of the box:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX tbl_uni_idx ON tbl (a_id, b_id, c_id, ident)
WHERE date_a IS NULL AND date_b IS NULL;
```

Comment: It thought about doing this, but it adds another layer where stuff can go wrong, I don't particularly like it.